# Analytics Real Time Active Users on Particular Page

Tags: google-analytics, real-time

I want to get the count of active users based on separate pages. What I'm getting is the count of Active Users on whole website.

I am using this code,

```
$metrics    =   'ga:screenviews';
$optParams  =   array('dimensions' => 'ga:screenName');    
try {
    $results = $service->data_realtime->get(
      $GA_VIEW_ID,
      'rt:activeUsers',
      $optParams);
} catch (apiServiceException $e) {
  // Handle API service exceptions.
  $error = $e->getMessage();
}
```

Is there any extra parameters to be added for getting for a particular page.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to apply filters to your query. Also please note, that dimensions and metrics differ from general reporting API, and start with `rt:`, in metrics, dimensions, and filters as well. Extending your code would look something like this:

```
$metrics    =   'rt:screenViews';
$optParams  =   array('dimensions' => 'rt:screenName',
                      'filters' => 'rt:screenName==somescreen);    
try {
    $results = $service->data_realtime->get(
      $GA_VIEW_ID,
      'rt:activeUsers',
      $optParams);
} catch (apiServiceException $e) {
  // Handle API service exceptions.
  $error = $e->getMessage();
}
```

Although not the latest version, but the syntax of filter operators is explained [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters).
Please find the full list of real time metrics and dimensions [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/dimsmets/).